# Is there a function that plots your breakpoint in R?

Tags: r

I have found my breakpoints in my data using the strucchange and tidyverse library then using the plot.ts() and then breakpoints() function. I have 3 breakpoints in my data and would like to have them show up on my graph as breaks in my trend line. I have done this manually but would like to find an automated way to create these breaks at my break points. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcnNH.jpg)
My breakdates that correlate with my breakpoints also do not show up as dates. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLPTp.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, AllisonRobertson! Can you [edit] your question for two things? (1) Please don't post code/data as images, as it breaks screen-readers (vis-impaired need help too) and does not allow us to use it. I will not spend time *transcribing* sample data you have readily available on your R console. And (2) please provide a more reproducible question to include sample data in a more digestible format (gold-standard is `dput(x)`). Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for great pointers in that regard. Thank you, and welcome!